# Are the eigenvalues of $AB$ equal to the eigenvalues of $BA$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

First of all, am I being crazy in thinking that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $AB$, where $A$ and $B$ are both $N \times N$ matrices (not necessarily invertible), then $\lambda$ is also an eigenvalue of $BA$?

If it's not true, then under what conditions is it true or not true?

If it is true, can anyone point me to a citation?  I couldn't find it in a quick perusal of Horn & Johnson.  I have seen a couple proofs that the characteristic polynomial of $AB$ is equal to the characteristic polynomial of $BA$, but none with any citations.

A trivial proof would be OK, but a citation is better.

Comment: Have you tried to find a counter example using basic 2x2 matrices?

Comment: Here are 7 proofs: https://www.ias.ac.in/article/fulltext/reso/007/01/0088-0093

Answer (score 137, accepted):

If $v$ is an eigenvector of $AB$ for some nonzero $\lambda$, then $Bv\ne0$
and $$\lambda Bv=B(ABv)=(BA)Bv,$$ so $Bv$ is an eigenvector for $BA$ with the same eigenvalue. If $0$ is an eigenvalue of $AB$ then $0=\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)=\det(BA)$ so $0$ is also an eigenvalue of $BA$.

More generally, Jacobson's lemma in operator theory states that for any two bounded operators $A$ and $B$ acting on a Hilbert space $H$ (or more generally, for any two elements of a Banach algebra), the non-zero points of the spectrum of $AB$ coincide with those of the spectrum of $BA$.

Comment: Bob, I am a little confused on your proof. How did you know to use the trick $Bv \ne 0$ to prove this?

Comment: @diimension You just take an eigenvector of $AB$ and do the only calculation you can. Then it turns out that $Bv$ fulfills the eigenvector equation for $BA$, so you hope that it is not 0 and check this in the end. There's no need to know it at the start of the calculation.

Comment: @Phira thank you very much!

Comment: I know this is an ancient thread but hopefully you're still lurking out there somewhere. How come you need to hope that $\lambda\ne 0$? Doesn't the argument still work just fine in the case where $\lambda=0$?

Comment: @crf No -- the trouble is that when $Bv=0$, maybe $v$ is not in the range of $A$. The argument given for $\lambda\ne0$ works in Hilbert space, for example, but for $\lambda=0$ the result is not generally true there: On the infinite sequence space $\ell^2$, let $A$ be the right shift ($A(x_1,x_2,\ldots)=(0,x_1,x_2,\ldots)$, and $B$ the left shift. Then $AB(1,0,\ldots)=0$, but $BA$ is the identity.

Comment: More specifically: in the case that $Bv=0$, the equations $\lambda B v = B(AB v) = (BA)Bv$ from Bob’s answer still hold (because all those expressions vanish), but it is no longer the case that these expressions imply that $Bv$ is an eigenvector of $BA$. (For *any* matrix $M$, we of course have $Mw=0$ when $w=0$, but we don’t say $w$ is an eigenvector of $M$ with eigenvalue $0$.) But this counterexample relies on having an infinite dimensional vector space, and strictly speaking the original question presupposed finite-dimensional matrices.

Answer (score 32):

It is true that the eigenvalues (counting multiplicity) of $AB$ are the same as those of $BA$.

This is a corollary of [Theorem 1.3.22 in the second edition of "Matrix Analysis" by Horn and Johnson](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=5I5AYeeh0JUC&lpg=PP1&dq=horn%20and%20johnson&pg=PA65#v=onepage&q=horn%20and%20johnson&f=false), which is Theorem 1.3.20 in the first edition.

Paraphrasing from the cited Theorem: If $A$ is an $m$ by $n$ matrix and $B$ is an $n$ by $m$ matrix with $n \geq m$
then the characteristic polynomial $p_{BA}$ of $BA$ is related to the characteristic polynomial $p_{AB}$ of $AB$ by
$$p_{BA}(t) = t^{n-m} p_{AB}(t).$$

In your case, $n = m$, so $p_{BA} = p_{AB}$ and it follows that the eigenvalues (counting multiplicity) of $AB$ and $BA$ are the same.

You can see Horn and Johnson's proof in the Google Books link above. A similar proof was given in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/311362) from Maisam Hedyelloo.

Comment: Nice answer, thanks!! Is there a way to relate the eigenvectors of $AB$ and $BA?$  when $A, B$ have different, compatible dimensions?Yes, I see that if $v\ne 0$ is an eigenvector of $AB$, then $BA(Bv)= \lambda(Bv),$ provided $Bv \ne 0.$ So there's a catch there it seems, what I'm looking for is a theorem that'd completely relates the eigenvectors of $AB$ and $BA.$ I'm more interested in the case where $A=X, B=X^{T}.$

Comment: Yes, this has the added benefit of proving the equal algebraic multiplicity.

Answer (score 29):

Here is an alternative proof for this result, following Exercises 6.2.8-9 of Hoffman & Kunze's *Linear Algebra* (p. 190):

---

**Lemma:** Let $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{F})$, where $\mathbb{F}$ is an arbitrary field. If $I-AB$ is invertible, then so is $I-BA$, and

$$(I-BA)^{-1}=I+B(I-AB)^{-1}A.$$

**Proof of Lemma:** Since $I-AB$ is invertible,

\begin{align}
&I=(I-AB)(I-AB)^{-1}=(I-AB)^{-1}-AB(I-AB)^{-1}\\
&\implies (I-AB)^{-1} = I+ AB(I-AB)^{-1}.
\end{align}

Then we have

\begin{align}
I+B(I-AB)^{-1}A&= I+B[I+ AB(I-AB)^{-1}]A= I+BA+BAB(I-AB)^{-1}A\\
\implies I&=I+B(I-AB)^{-1}A-BA-BAB(I-AB)^{-1}A\\
&=I[I+B(I-AB)^{-1}A]-BA[I+B(I-AB)^{-1}A]\\
&=(I-BA)[I+B(I-AB)^{-1}A].\checkmark.
\end{align}

---

**Proposition:** $\forall A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{F}):$ $AB$ and $BA$ have the same eigenvalues.

**Proof:** Let $\alpha\in\mathbb{F}$ be an eigenvalue of $AB$. If $\alpha=0$, then $0=\det(0I-AB)=\det(-A)\det(B)=\det(B)\det(-A)=\det(0I-BA)$ and so $0$ is an eigenvalue of $BA$ also.

Otherwise $\alpha\neq0$. Suppose $\alpha$ is not an eigenvalue of $BA$. Then $0\neq\det(\alpha I-BA)=\alpha^n\det(I-(\frac{1}{\alpha}B)A)$. Then $0\neq\det(I-(\frac{1}{\alpha}B)A),$ so that $I-(\frac{1}{\alpha}B)A$ is invertible. By the lemma above we know that $I-A(\frac{1}{\alpha}B)$ is invertible as well, meaning $0\neq\det(I-A(\frac{1}{\alpha}B))=\det(I-\frac{1}{\alpha}AB) \implies 0\neq\det(\alpha I-AB)$. But we assumed $\alpha$ to be an eigenvalue for $AB$, $\unicode{x21af}$.

Comment: Do we need the condition of invertibility of $A$ or $B$ here?

Comment: @StubbornAtom No, the arguments I presented make no use of that condition ($M_n(\Bbb{F})$ is the set of all $n\times n$ matrices with entries from $\Bbb{F}$).

Comment: Amazing answer. Thank you..

Comment: How u get $det(αI- BA) = α^n$ ?

Comment: The equation doesn't end there, and determinant is multilinear on columns.

Answer (score 11):

Notice that $\lambda$ being an eigenvalue of $AB$ implies that $\det(AB-\lambda I)=0$ which implies that $$\det(A^{-1})\det(AB-\lambda I)\det(B^{-1})=0=\det(A^{-1}(AB-\lambda I)B^{-1})=\det((B-\lambda A^{-1})B^{-1}) $$ $$=\det(I-\lambda A^{-1}B^{-1}) = 0.$$
This further implies that $$\det(BA)\det(I-\lambda A^{-1}B^{-1})=\det(BA(I-\lambda A^{-1}B^{-1}))=\det(BA-\lambda I)=0,$$
i.e., $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $BA$.
This proof holds only for invertible matrices $A$ and $B$ though. For singular matrices you can show that $0$ is a common eigenvalue, but I can't think of a way to show that the rest of the eigenvalues are equal.