# $\| AB\|_\square \leq 1$ implies $\| BA\|_\triangle \leq 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

In this post norm denotes a matrix norm, i.e. it is sub-multiplicative. All matrices are real. $A$ is of size $n \times k$ with independent columns ($k \leq n$). $B$ is of size $k \times n$.

Let $\| \cdot \|_\square$ be some arbitrary matrix norm. Assume $\| AB\|_\square \leq 1$. Then we know $\rho(AB) \leq 1$. Then we know from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124888/are-the-eigenvalues-of-ab-equal-to-the-eigenvalues-of-ba-citation-needed) that $\rho(BA) \leq 1$.

Edit: thanks to @loupblanc I realized this was incorrect. <s>From this we know that there must be a matrix norm $\| \cdot \|_\triangle$ such that $\| BA\|_\triangle \leq 1$.</s> . In fact we only know that there is a norm which is arbitrarily close to the spectral radius.

I am interested in whether there is an easy way of defining $\| \cdot \|_\triangle$ from $\| \cdot \|_\square$. For example, is it true that $\| \cdot \|_\triangle = \|F (\cdot) Q\|_\square$ for some choice of $F$ and $Q$?

---

Edit: when I say the norm $\| \cdot \|_\square$ is sub-multiplicative I mean it is sub-multiplicative in the space of $n \times n$ matrices. I *do not mean* $\| A B \|_\square \leq \|A\|_\square \| B \|_\square$, which indeed doesn't make sense. What I mean that if, say, one decomposed $AB$ into a product of square matrices, i.e. $AB = C_1C_2$, where $C_1,C_2$ are square, *then* we would have $\| A B\|_\square = \| C_1 C_2 \|_\square \leq \| C_1 \|_\square \|  C_2 \|_\square $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Submultiplicative norms for non-square matrices obviously do not make sense, but with square matrices, I don't think what you originally wrote was wrong. More specifically, we have the following

> **Proposition.** Suppose $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb C)$. If $\rho(AB)=\|AB\|_\square\le1$ for some submultiplicative norm $\|\cdot\|_\square$, then there exists some submultiplicative matrix norm $\|\cdot\|_\triangle$ such that $\|BA\|_\triangle\le1$.

If $\rho(AB)<1$, the proposition is obvious because $\rho(AB)=\rho(BA)$ and the spectral radius is the infinum of all submultiplicative matrix norms. So, it suffices to consider only the case $\rho(AB)=\rho(BA)=\|AB\|_\square=1$, and we need to find some norm such that $\|BA\|_\triangle=1$.

As $\rho(AB)=1$, we have $1 = \left(\rho(AB)\right)^k = \rho((AB)^k) \le \|(AB)^k\|_\square \le \|AB\|_\square^k = 1$ and in turn $\|(AB)^k\|_\square=1$ for all natural number $k$. Hence $AB$ is power bounded. As $(BA)^{k+1}=B(AB)^kA$, the product $BA$ and in turn its Jordan form are power bounded too. Since all matrix norms (submultiplicative or not) on $M_n(\mathbb C)$ are equivalent, the Frobenius norms of the powers of the Jordan form of $BA$ are uniformly bounded. It follows that for each **unit** eigenvalue of $BA$, its algebraic and geometric multiplicities coincide. That is, in the Jordan decomposition $BA=PJP^{-1}$, we may assume that
$$
J=\pmatrix{T&0\\ 0&D},
$$
where $T$ is a direct sum of (upper triangular) Jordan blocks for eigenvalues whose magnitudes are strictly smaller than $1$, and $D$ is a diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries have unit moduli.

Now suppose the size of $T$ is $m\times m$. Let $\epsilon>0$ and $\Lambda=\operatorname{diag}(1,\epsilon,\epsilon^2,\ldots,\epsilon^{m-1})\oplus I_{n-m}$. When $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small, the superdiagonal of $\Lambda^{-1}J\Lambda$ can be made arbitrarily small and the diagonal entries remain invariant. Therefore the spectral norm $\|\Lambda^{-1}J\Lambda\|_2=\sigma(\Lambda^{-1}J\Lambda)$ is equal to $1$. Consequently, if we define
$$
\|X\|_\triangle = \|\Lambda^{-1}P^{-1}XP\Lambda\|_2,
$$
we get $\|BA\|_\triangle=1$.

Comment: @ user1551 , pretty proof. In fact you show that: there is a sub-mult. norm $||.||$ s.t. $\rho(U)=||U||$ iff the eigenvalues of $U$ of maximal modulus are semi-simple.

Comment: @loupblanc Thanks. Initially I thought this is a known result, but I couldn't find it anywhere in the books offhand. Google showed nothing either. The closest thing I can find is the [characterisation](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/242984064_On_matrices_having_equal_spectral_radius_and_spectral_norm) of radial matrices. Do you know if this is a known result?

Comment: @ user1551 , I did not know this equivalence. Householder speaks about this result in one of his paper; you can read for free the first 2 pages as follows: with Google, do "S. Householder, Minimal matrix norms" and click on the Springer link. Note that it is a reference cited by Goldberg-Zwaz.

Comment: @loupblanc Thanks a lot. Minimal norms (for *fixed* matrices!) ... of course ... that makes much sense. I have looked for useful results about minimal norms before answering the question, but quickly abandoned the search because such norms (the usual ones, not Householder's) are minimal for all matrices.

Comment: @user1551: The book Numerical Analysis by Ortega has a proof  of the same. In it such matrices are said to be " of class M".

Comment: @me10240 Thanks for the information. I'll read it when I can get a copy.

Answer (score 1):

@ ziutek , a matrix norm $||.||$ is defined on a space $M_{n,m}$. If $||.||$ is sub-multiplicative, then necessarily $m=n$ and $A$ cannot be rectangular. Moreover there is a big mistake in your line 5. Indeed if $\rho(BA)\leq 1$, then, we have only the following:  for every $\epsilon>0$, there is an induced norm $N()$ s.t. $N(BA)\leq \rho(BA)+\epsilon$.

Assume for example that $B$ is invertible and let $N(U)=||B^{-1}UB||$. Then $N()$ is sub-multiplicative norm (easy). Moreover $N(BA)=||AB||=1$. It remains the case when $A,B$ are non-invertible.

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer. I clarified the question a little bit and stated explicitly what I mean by sub-multiplicative.