# A question in simillarity of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a 4x4 matrix 
$$ A = 
\left[ 
\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right] $$
and i want to check if there is any similar matrix of matrix $A$ of the form:
$$ B = 
\left[ 
\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & x & y \\
0 & 0 & z & w \\
a & b & 0 & 0 \\
c & d & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}
\right] $$
Is there any way to come in a conclusion if there such of this form similarity ?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

note that two similar matrix have the same caracteristic polinomial $P(t)$, if we calcul this polynomial for each matrix we tack an have coefficient -1 at $t^3$ and othere $0$ as coefficient at $t^3$ so  the similarity is impossible

Comment: In other words, they clearly have different traces! That's simpler than my roundabout argument.

Comment: very good, exactely, thanks

Comment: But this can be a generic criterion for making a conclusion and for other matrices? For example if i have the matrix
$$C = 
\left[ 
\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}
\right]$$ which has a characteristic Polynomial $\lambda^4 -1 $ what can i say for this case ?I suppose that the term $\lambda^2$ in char polynomial of matrix $B$ possibly might not be 0.

Comment: two matrix have the same caracteristic polynomial not amplique there are similar matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Working over $\mathbb C$, let's write $B$ as a block matrix
$$ B = \begin{bmatrix}0 & X \\ E & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$
Then
$$ B^2 = \begin{bmatrix}XE & 0 \\ 0 & EX\end{bmatrix} $$
and since $XE$ and $EX$ [have the same eigenvalues](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124888/are-the-eigenvalues-of-ab-equal-to-the-eigenvalues-of-ba-citation-needed), we can do a case analysis on the number of these eigenvalues:

- If there's only one eigenvalue for $EX$ and $XE$, then $B^2$ has only one eigenvalue. However, [Wolfram Alpha tells us](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diagonalize%7B%7B0,1,0,0%7D,%7B0,0,1,0%7D,%7B1,0,0,0%7D,%7B0,1,1,1%7D%7D%5e2) that $A^2$ has three different eigenvalues, so $A$ cannot be similar to such a $B$.
- On the other hand, if $EX$ has two eigenvalues, it is diagonalizable, and so is $XE$, so $B^2$ is diagonalizable. But Wolfram Alpha just showed us that $A^2$ *isn't* diagonalizable, so $A$ is not similar to this kind of $B$ either.

Since $A$ is not similar to any $B$-shaped matrix over $\mathbb C$, this is in particular not the case over $\mathbb R$ either.

Comment: Thank you very much! You were very Helpfull !

Comment: @mpouxa: Consider accepting m.idaya's much simpler argument instead.

Comment: if i find a diagonalizable matrix in the second case of your answer is it enough to say that the matrix are similar ? For example i take the matrix $C$ as i used in m.idaya's answer, where 
$$C =  \left[  \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right]$$. $C^2$ is diagonalizable but for the first case it has 2 different eigenvalues.

Comment: @mpouxa: That is similar to $$\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$ simply by permuting indices.

Comment: Yes, But first i'm looking for a generic creterion to understand for more difficult cases when i have to consider this kind of simillarity . For example an other matrix that i'm trying to check is: 
$$D =  \left[  \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right]$$ which also agrees with the second case of your answer but not with the first