# Are the eigenvalues of the matrix AB equal to the eigenvalues of the matrix BA

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form

Are the eigenvalues of the matrix  $
AB
$
 equal to the eigenvalues of the matrix $
BA
$ 
.
Where the matrices A And B of sizes $
{3}\mathrm{\times}{5}
$
and $
{5}\mathrm{\times}{3}
$
Respectively
 .then how can we find the Jordan form of the matrix  $
BA
$
 if we have the matrix:

$
{AB}\mathrm{{=}}\left[{\begin{array}{l}
{{1}\hspace{0.33em}{1}\hspace{0.33em}{0}}\\
{{0}\hspace{0.33em}{1}\hspace{0.33em}{0}}\\
{{0}\hspace{0.33em}{0}\hspace{0.33em}\mathrm{{-}}{1}}
\end{array}}\right]
$

Comment: If $A B x = \lambda x$, then $(B A) B x = \lambda B x$. When $x \neq 0$, and $\lambda \neq 0$, this proves that $B x$ is an eigenvector of $B A$ for the same eigenvalue. For $\lambda = 0$, it is an eigenvalue if and only if $A$ or $B$ is singular, then it is also an eigenvalue of $B A$

Comment: Ok  I will try it thanks

Comment: That means that the eigenvalues of both matrices are equal .Is it right ?

Comment: I think so yes, provided $A$ and $B$ are square matrices.

Comment: They are not in the assumption.

Comment: Indeed :) but AB and BA can be square when A and B are only rectangular! Also note the result that $B P(AB) = P(BA) B$ when $P$ is a polynomial. This can be useful for Jordan with $P(X) = (X-\lambda)^k$.

Comment: @Math1000 No, $A$ could be $p\times q$ and $B$ $q\times p$.

Comment: @Gribouillis Indeed. I will retract my previous false statements :)

Comment: So now should I find the eigenvalues of AB and their corresponding eigenvectors that are the same for both of matrices AB and BA.

Comment: The more natural question, if $A,B$ are not square and $AB$ is smaller than $BA$ (which we may assume WLOG), is whether the eigenvalues of $AB$ are *contained* in those of $BA$. The spectra can't possibly be the same, taking multiplicities into account. So even if you do have this containment, there is a followup question of "what extra eigenvalues does $BA$ have?"

Comment: The Jordan form of $AB$ and $BA$ are not necessarily equal, even when $A$ and $B$ are square.  So in the general case it's not true that one is determined by the other, though perhaps in this case it is.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $A$ and $B$ are square: $BA$ is invertible, so $B$ is invertible. Note that
$$
B^{-1}(BA)B= AB
$$
so $AB$ is similar to $BA$.

---

Per the clarification: it is well known that $A$ and $B$ will have the same non-zero eigenvalues, as explained in the other answer.  What's more: $AB$ and $BA$ have the same rank, which means that $BA$ (a $5 \times 5$ matrix) has eigenvalue $0$ with algebraic *and* geometric multiplicity $2$.

We must exclude, however, the possibility that $BA$ is diagonalizable.  Equivalently, we want to show that since $(AB - I)^2$ has a lower rank than $(AB - I)$, $(BA - I)^2$ has a lower rank than $(BA - I)$.

---

$AB$ has an eigenvector $x$ assoicated with $1$, and a generalized eigenvector $y$ satisfying $ABy = y + x$.  Thus, we see that $BA$ has eigenvector $Bx$, since
$$
(BA)(Bx) = B(AB)x = Bx
$$
moreover, $BA$ has generalized eigenvector $By$ satisfying
$$
(BA)(By) = B(AB)y = B(y + x) = (By) + (Bx)
$$
Thus, $BA$ indeed fails to be diagonalizable.  Thus, we know its Jordan form.

Comment: But the matrices aren't square .in the assumption

Comment: Well, you added that after I wrote my answer. I'll add something

Comment: Ok I am waiting

Comment: Are there any ideas?

Comment: Thanks really a lot but I didn't get it what should I try to do firstly?

Comment: See my latest edit.

Comment: İs there any difference that the matrices are complex matrices

Comment: @user401187 there is no difference

Comment: So what is the relationship between the Jordan form and the matrix is not diagonalizable ?

Comment: @user401187 a matrix is diagonalizable if and only if its Jordan form is diagonal, which is to say that all Jordan blocks have size $1$.

Comment: In our example we obtained that AB fails to be diagonalizable soo

Comment: @user401187 we know the eigenvalues of $BA$, we know that it has two Jordan blocks for $0$, and we know that it has one Jordan block for $1$.  So, we know the Jordan form of $BA$.

Comment: Thanks really ..but still don't know how we proved that the eigenvalues are the same ?????

Comment: Well, the **non-zero** eigenvalues are the same. The other answer provides a valid proof.  See also [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124888/are-the-eigenvalues-of-ab-equal-to-the-eigenvalues-of-ba-citation-needed)

Comment: I have just focused on why the matrix failed to be diagonalisable

Answer (score 2):

Denote $$C=\begin{bmatrix}{\lambda I}&{A}\\{B}&{I}\end{bmatrix},\quad D=\begin{bmatrix}{-I}&{0}\\{B}&{-\lambda I}\end{bmatrix}.$$ Then, $$CD=\begin{bmatrix}{\lambda I}&{A}\\{B}&{I}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}{-I}&{0}\\{B}&{-\lambda I}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}{-\lambda I+AB}&{-\lambda A}\\{0}&{-\lambda I}\end{bmatrix},$$ $$DC=\begin{bmatrix}{-I}&{0}\\{B}&{-\lambda I}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}{\lambda I}&{A}\\{B}&{I}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}{-\lambda I}&{- A}\\{0}&{BA-\lambda I}\end{bmatrix}.$$ Using that $\det(CD)=\det(DC)$ we get: $$\det (AB-\lambda I)(-\lambda)^n=(-\lambda)^n\det(BA-\lambda I)$$ So $\det(AB-\lambda I)=\det(BA-\lambda I)$ that is,  $AB$ y $BA$ have the same characteristic polynomial as a consequence the same eigenvalues and besides (this is important), *with the same algebraic multiplicity.*

Comment: I think it's like a special case .we can't depend on it

Comment: It seems that your problem has two parts. If $A$ and $B$ are square matrices with the same order, the previous proof is general.

Comment: Yes. I think that