# Characteristic Polynomial $AB =$ characteristic polynomial $ BA$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $A,B$ matrix on $\mathbb{R}$ size $n\times n$. How can I prove that $det(xI - AB) = det(xI - BA)$ if $A$ and $B$ are singular matrix

Comment: I take it you know how to prove it when the matrices are nonsingular. You can then get the singular case by continuity.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2092168/are-the-eigenvalues-of-the-matrix-ab-equal-to-the-eigenvalues-of-the-matrix-ba and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1787537/help-with-understanding-the-proof-for-ab-and-ba-have-the-same-characteristi and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378303/show-ab-and-ba-have-the-same-eigenvalues and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232561/eigen-values-proof and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2163564/eigenvalues-for-a-product-of-matrices and many others.

Comment: @GerryMyerson He did not specify the field (or whether the coefficients even are in a field).

Comment: @Igor, the very first sentence of the question uses the standard notation for the field of real numbers.

Comment: @GerryMyerson True. But the statement is true over any commutative ring, as you know better than I.