# Why my Alternative Proof for eigenvalues of AB and BA Fails

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

My book offers a different proof for the following question and after some consideration I reckon my attempt is incorrect, but I cannot pinpoint why.

> Let A,B be square matrices of the same size. Show that the eigenvalues of AB and BA are equal.

I wrote $det(AB - \lambda I) = det(AB) - det(\lambda I) = det(BA) - det(\lambda I) = det(BA - \lambda I)$ ergo the characteristic polynomials are equal.

I ask: flaw in reasoning is where? Thanks.

Comment: $\det (AB- \lambda I) \neq \det (AB) -\det (\lambda I) $ Also see [Alp Uzman's answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124888/are-the-eigenvalues-of-ab-equal-to-the-eigenvalues-of-ba-citation-needed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flaw is while applying determinants,see that $det(A+B)\neq det(A) + det(B)$ in general. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thought there was linearity. Woops.

Comment: @Krpcannon the following is true , $det(AB) = det(A).det(B)$ , and other is $Trace(A+B) = Trace(A) + Trace(B)$ , where $A$ and $B$ are two matrices of same size.and also i think you would have figured out that $det(AB) = det(BA)$

Comment: Also you can see some other properties of determinants here -http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~llpku/2007fall415/hw912.pdf

Answer (score 0):

In general, $\det(X+Y)\ne\det(X)+\det(Y)$, but in your case it *could* be true.

However, if the identity you use were true, you'd get 
$$
\det(AB-\lambda I)=\det(AB)-\det(\lambda I)=\det(AB)-\lambda^n
$$
which is clearly absurd: take $B=I$ and $A$ any matrix with eigenvalues $1$ and $2$. (The identity is valid for $n=1$, actually, but it's not so useful in that case.)