# equality of spectrums

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ and $B$ be both square matrices with the same dimension. Prove that the following is correct:

$S_p(AB)=S_p(BA)$ , where $S_p$ is the set of eigenvalues.

I am really confused by how I am supposed to find the eigenvalues of these unknown matrices. So if anyone could explain it a bit, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: By the way: the eigenvalues of a matrix form its *spectrum*.  The plural of spectrum is *spectrums* or *spectra*, not *spectres*.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/124888/81360)

Comment: okay, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you mean by "finding the eigenvalues of unknown matrices", but clearly you're misunderstanding how these proofs are meant to go.  In any case: to show that two matrices have the same eigenvalues, the most convenient approach is often to show that they have the same characteristic polynomial.

**Approach 1:** Using either [Sylvester's determinant identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_determinant_identity) or [something equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma#Generalization), one can show that for all $t \neq 0$, we have
$$
\det(tI - AB) = \det(tI - BA)
$$
if the polynomials are equal for all $t \neq 0$, then they must be the same polynomial.

**Approach 2:** Note that $AB$ is similar to $BA$ whenever $B$ is invertible (why?).  It follows that $\det(t I - BA) = \det(t I - AB)$.  When $B$ is not invertible, we note that
$$
\det(t I - BA) = 
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \det(t I - (B + \epsilon I)A) = 
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \det(t I - A(B + \epsilon I)) = 
\det(t I - AB)
$$
since $B + \epsilon I$ is invertible when $|\epsilon|$ is sufficiently small and non-zero.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the 1st approach a bit more? I haven't really learned that method, so I am not sure how to use it? Thanks