# Prove that if $λ$ is an eigenvalue of $AB$ then $λ$ is also an eigenvalue of $BA$.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Firstly, i understand that there is a much detailed thread on this at [Are the eigenvalues of $AB$ equal to the eigenvalues of $BA$? (Citation needed!)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124888/are-the-eigenvalues-of-ab-equal-to-the-eigenvalues-of-ba-citation-needed), however, they are of a much detailed concept for me to understand at my current level.

Nevertheless,

> Prove that if $λ$ is an eigenvalue of $AB$ then $λ$ is also an
>   eigenvalue of $BA$.

I wish to approach this proving question by considering $λ = 0$ and $λ ≠ 0$.

My current attempt is that if $λ = 0$, det$(AB)$ is obviously not equal to 0. And i'm basically stuck here, how does this relates to BA in having the same eigenvalue?

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are not square, then $0$ may be an eigenvalue of $AB$ without it being an eigenvalue of $BA$.

Comment: But yes, if $\lambda = 0$ is an eigenvalue of $AB$, then obviously, $\det(AB) = 0$. If $A$ and $B$ are square, then clearly also $\det(BA) = 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

$$
ABx=\lambda x \quad \Rightarrow \quad BABx=BA(Bx)=B\lambda x=\lambda (Bx)
$$