# Spectrum of product of self adjoint operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let $\mathcal{B}(F)$ the algebra of all bounded linear operators on an infinite-dimensional complex Hilbert space $F$.

> Let $T,S\in\mathcal{B}(F)$, be two self-adjoint operators. Why
>   $$\sigma (TS)\subseteq\mathbb{R}?$$

Comment: The inclusion is not true in general. It is true when at least one of $S,T$ is positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** You need additionally that one of the operators is positive, see the comment by Martin Argerami below.

This follows from combining the next two facts:
$$
\sigma( T  S ) \cup \{0\} = \sigma( S  T ) \cup \{0\},
$$
this is sometimes called "Jacobson's lemma", and it can be proved by using, e.g., https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1928728/58577

The second fact is
$$
\sigma( U ) = \overline{\sigma( U^\star) }.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If $T,S\in\mathcal{B}(F)^+$, it is true that
$$\sigma (TS)\subseteq\mathbb{R}_+?$$

Comment: Yes. By introducing the square-root $\sqrt{T}$, you have $\sigma( T \, S) \cup\{0\} = \sigma(\sqrt{T} \, S \, \sqrt{T}) \cup \{0\} \subset [0,\infty)$.

Comment: $$
\sigma( T \, S ) \cup \{0\} = \sigma( S \, T ) \cup \{0\},
$$ is true even if $T$ and $S$ aren't self-adjoint?

Comment: Yes, see the link above

Comment: Thank you but the link is for matrice and here $F$ is an infinite dimentional Hilbert space.

Comment: The arguments are the same. It is never used that those are matrices.

Comment: -1: This answer is wrong. Consider for instance $$
S=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix},\ \ \ \ T=\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: @MartinArgerami: Thank you. Indeed, my answer only shows that $\overline{\sigma(S T)} \cup \{0\} = \sigma(S T) \cup \{0\}$.