# Spectrum of product of self-adjoint operators contained in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: spectral-theory, c-star-algebras, self-adjoint-operators

Let $S,T$ be self-adjoint bounded operators on a complex Hilbert space. In this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2671912/spectrum-of-product-of-self-adjoint-operators), it is shown that $\sigma(ST)\subset\mathbb{R}$. The answerer uses that $\sigma(ST)\cup\{0\}=\sigma(TS)\cup\{0\}$ and that $\sigma(U)=\sigma(U^{*})^{*}$ for any operator $U$. I know that these results are indeed true. But how does he use these results to conclude that $\sigma(ST)\subset\mathbb{R}$?

If I play around with his arguments, I find that $$\sigma(ST)\cup\{0\}=\sigma(TS)\cup\{0\}=\sigma((TS)^{*})^{*}\cup\{0\}=\sigma(S^{*}T^{*})^{*}\cup\{0\}=\sigma(ST)^{*}\cup\{0\}.$$

But, for example, $\mathbb{C}^{*}=\mathbb{C}$ and of course $\mathbb{C}\not\subset\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I cannot make sense of that answer. More importantly, the assertion is not true if we only require $S,T$ to be selfadjoint. Consider 
$$
S=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix},\ \ \ \ T=\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then $\sigma(ST)=\{i,-i\}$.

If you require, say $S\geq0$, then the assertion does work because 
$$
\sigma(ST)\cup\{0\}=\sigma(S^{1/2}TS^{1/2})\cup\{0\}\subset\mathbb R. 
$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Doesn't this only work for positive operators? (Taking square roots?)

Comment: No. The operator $-I$ is not positive and it has square root $i\,I$. You can do that for any selfadjiont.

Comment: I agree with you example, but it leaves me a bit puzzled. In any C*-algebra $A$, the set positive elements is precisely $A^{+}=\{a^{*}a:a\in A\}$ (see thm 2.2.5 in Murphy's book on C*-algebras). But then this would imply that $T=Z^{*}Z$ is automatically positive.

Comment: $(iI)^{2}=-I$, but $(iI)^{*}=-iI$. So $iI$ is a square root of $-I$, but it is not a self-adjoint square.

Comment: You are right, my bad. The square of a selfadjoint is positive.

Comment: And the assertion is not true. Please see the edit.